# JavaScript: Combining similar functions

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple functions that does the same thing over and over again but with a different object data passed from the external JSON file. These data are called Data1, Data2, and Data3 which I have declared them as a variables of Data1_Data, Data2_Data, and Data3_Data.

I am wondering how I can combine these functions so that I can write one function, that passes in the corresponding JSON data objects.

Background Information: So the functions loop through the external JSON dataset (tremendous amount) and displays the n-th information to the assigned IDs. Each function is currently assigned to a particular data object within JSON file, as for the example here: Data1, Data2, and Data3.

JSfiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/3mL0d6Lb/

```
<div class="Dboxes">
<span class="Title"> Data1/Data2 </span>
    <div class="TableContainer">
        <div class="Value"> 
            <span id="Data1" class="metrics">##</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableContainer">
       <div class="Value"> 
       <span id="Data2" class="metrics">##</span> 
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableContainer">
        <div class="Value"> 
        <span id="Data3" class="metrics">##</span> 
        </div>
     </div>
```

```
.Dboxes {
            width: 140px;
            height: 140px; 
            background: linear-gradient(#00395c 0%, #000000 50%, #00395c 100%);
            padding-top: 2px;
            padding-left: 2px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
            position:relative;
            color: white;
        }

.Value
{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}


.TableContainer
{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  height: 25px;
}
.TitleImage
{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScripts

```
// Setting up the Json 
var counter = 0; // Trial 
var previous_value = null;

$(document).ready(function () {       

  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

       myJson();

    });

// Below is the function to draw data from Json        
function myJson() {

    $.getJSON("Dataset.json", function (response) {

        var i = 1380; //start demo at last hour of data.

        var looping = setInterval(function () {
        var TrialCount = response.length;
            var Info = response[counter];
            var Data1_Data = Info.Data1;
            var Data2_Data = Info.Data2;
      var Data3_Data = Info.Data3;

            CompareData1();
            CompareData2();
      CompareData3();

            function CompareData1() {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    prev_Data1_Data = Data1_Data; 
                }
                if (Data1_Data > prev_Data1_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data1_Data - prev_Data1_Data) >= prev_Data1_Data / 2 ))
                    document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/yeltri.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data1_Data - prev_Data1_Data) <= prev_Data1_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }
                else if (Data1_Data < prev_Data1_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data1_Data - prev_Data1_Data) >= prev_Data1_Data / 2))
                    document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/yeltriDn.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data1_Data - prev_Data1_Data) <= prev_Data1_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }
                prev_Data1_Data = Data1_Data;
            }

            function CompareData2() {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    prev_Data2_Data = Data2_Data;
                }
                if (Data2_Data > prev_Data2_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data2_Data - prev_Data2_Data) >= prev_Data2_Data / 2 ))
                    document.getElementById("Data2_img").src = "img/yeltri.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data2_Data - prev_Data2_Data) <= prev_Data2_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data2_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }
                else if (Data2_Data < prev_Data2_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data2_Data - prev_Data2_Data) >= prev_Data2_Data / 2))
                    document.getElementById("Data2_img").src = "img/yeltriDn.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data2_Data - prev_Data2_Data) <= prev_Data2_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data2_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }

                prev_Data2_Data = Data2_Data;
            }

      function CompareData3() {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    prev_Data3_Data = Data3_Data;
                }
                if (Data3_Data > prev_Data3_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data3_Data - prev_Data3_Data) >= prev_Data3_Data / 2 ))
                    document.getElementById("Data3_img").src = "img/yeltri.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data3_Data - prev_Data3_Data) <= prev_Data3_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data3_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }
                else if (Data3_Data < prev_Data3_Data) {
                    if ((Math.abs(Data3_Data - prev_Data3_Data) >= prev_Data3_Data / 2))
                    document.getElementById("Data3_img").src = "img/yeltriDn.png";
                    else if ((Math.abs(Data3_Data - prev_Data3_Data) <= prev_Data3_Data / 2))
                        document.getElementById("Data3_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
                }

                prev_Data3_Data = Data3_Data;
            }

            document.getElementById("Data1").innerHTML = Data1_Data
            document.getElementById("Data2").innerHTML = Data2_Data
            document.getElementById("Data3").innerHTML = Data3_Data

            counter++;
            if (counter == TrialCount) clearInterval(looping);

        }, 100);
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't see where have you declared such variables as `prev_Data1_Data`. Are they global?

Comment: at end of each function, I declared prev_Data1_data by pointing to the Data1_Data

Comment: that's not good practice. What if `counter` will not be equal to `0` in first condition in function `CompareData1`? Then in the subsequent condition `if (Data1_Data > prev_Data1_Data) {` it will compare `Data1_Data` with undeclared variable `prev_Data1_Data`.

Comment: I can help you easily and provide combined and optimized function for you, but I want you to prepare that variables in proper way

Comment: I decided to provide an answer in a more explanatory way, because I believe @axchink can figure out their own personal way of optimizing the code. That's what **[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)** is for anyways

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You are right, it may encounter a problem in the first condition so I am thinking of declaring the prev_Data1_Data = Data1_Data before it runs. I will modify the code as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[for each function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)** on your `Info` object to loop through the properties in it, instead of using it individually.

```
CompareData(Info);

for(data in Info){
    if (Info.hasOwnProperty(data)) {
        CompareData(data, info[data]);
    }
}

function CompareData(data, data_value){
    // Modify your code here
}
```

The reason why I left a comment on the `CompareData` function is because of how you are currently using the following variables: `Data_#_Data` and `prev_Data#_Data`, where # means 1, 2 or 3, allow me to elaborate...

I believe you can substitute the use of these variables by using the `data_value` instead, which is `info[data]`. So by going with the code I provided, inside the `CompareData` function we can use the passed in object property `data` which is now named `data` for simplicity, in order to determine which Data (1, 2 or 3) we are dealing with.

I also passed the value of this property via `info[data]` so that we do not need to worry about it within the function itself... you may change this at any time.

So now you have your relevant information in the function, all you need to do is a simple check: `if(data === "Data1")` to check which Data you are dealing with. Implementing it would be something like this:

```
if(data === "Data1"){
    // ... some code before
    document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/grnsqr.png";
    // ... some code after
}
```

That would allow you to use the specific code geared to each property without duplicating the surrounding code, which is the point of your concern. If you look at the code below, it is an example of what you can do with this implementation... but bear in mind I am not writing the entire code for you, because I am leaving the final implementation up to you and your own style of coding.

```
function CompareData(data, data_value){
     var prev_data = 0;

     if (counter == 0) {
         prev_data = data_value; 
     }

     if (data_value > prev_data) {
         if ((Math.abs(data_value - prev_data) >= prev_data / 2 ))
             if(data === "Data1"){
                document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/yeltri.png";
             }
             else if(data === "Data2"){
                document.getElementById("Data1_img").src = "img/yeltri.png";
             }
             // ... Etcetera....
         }
     }
 }
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask in the comments below. If you code is working and you wish to optimize it, I highly recommend going to **[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)** and post your code there.